# Python - Add to list splices many times, optimization, algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, list, optimization, splice

I am trying to add a constant num_to_add to each list element of list I within a splice l[i:j(inclusive)] where I am given many queries of form [i, j, num_to_add].

Where t is of format [[i, j, num_to_add], [i, j, num_to_add], etc.]
I add each element of t to list I which is completely made of zeroes.

My current code is this:
I loop through the sublists in t, my queries, and add num_to_add to each list splice element. I output the number of elements in list I that are less than integer n.

How could I optimize this from a nested for loop? This is for a small section of a problem that could be applicable to other projects as well.

**EDIT 4:**
Sample input:

```
4
1
3
1 3 1
2 3 2
3 3 2
```

**EDIT 5:**
Full code:

```
I = [0] * int(input())
n = int(input())
j = int(input())
t = [list(map(int, input().split())) for i in range(j)]

tree = []
for i in range(1, 2*len(I)+1):
    tree.append([0,0])

def update(pos , left , right , i , j , val):

    ####updating segment tree to add value val in list l from index i to j

    i=max(i , left)
    j=min(j , right)
    if i > j:
       return

    if i==left and j==right:
       tree[pos][0] = tree[pos][0] + val*( j - i + 1 )
       tree[pos][1] = tree[pos][1] + val
       return

    mid = (left + right)/2

    ### the range breaks down into two parts left to mid and mid+1 to right 
    ### at positions 2*pos and 2*pos+1 in tree respectively

    update(2*pos , left , mid , i , j , val)
    update(2*pos + 1 , mid+1 , right , i , j , val) 
    tree[pos][0] = tree[2*pos][0] + tree[2*pos + 1][0] + tree[pos][1]*(right - left +1 ) 


def getvalue(pos , left , right , i , j ):

    ###gets sum of elements in list from index i to j in our case
    ### i will be equal to j , will see below 

    i = max(i , left)
    j=  min(j , right)
    if i > j:
        return 0
    if i==left and j==right:
        return tree[pos][0]

    mid = (left + right)/2 
    return getvalue(2*pos , left , mid , i , j) + getvalue(2*pos+1 , mid+1 , right , i , j) + tree[pos][1]*(j - i + 1)

###Remember l is 1 based indexed
for i in range( len(t) ):
    update(1 , 1 , len(I) , t[i][0] , t[i][1] , t[i][2])

ans = 0

###Remember l is 1 based indexed
for i in range(1 , len(I)+1):
   ###see we only use getvalue where i and j parameters of getvalue are same
   value = getvalue(1 , 1 , len(I) , i , i) 
   if value < n:
       ans = ans + 1

print(ans)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File, line 58, in <module>
    value = getvalue(1 , 1 , len(I) , i , i)
# A lot of these:
  File "/home/max3/Documents/Python/DMOJ TCE Battle Positions.py", line 47, in getvalue
    return getvalue(2*pos , left , mid , i , j) + getvalue(2*pos+1 , mid+1 , right , i , j) + tree[pos][1]*(j - i + 1)
# And one of this.
  File "/home/max3/Documents/Python/DMOJ TCE Battle Positions.py", line 44, in getvalue
    return tree[pos][0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: is num_to_add constant along all queries ?

Comment: you should lookup segment tree or binary index tree, you will find alot of similar questions on stackoverflow itself

Comment: No, it is distinct for certain queries. Do you have any specific links?

Comment: http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=lowestCommonAncestor

Comment: read segment trees here

Answer (score 1):

A segment tree provides you with ability to update and retrieve say sum of elements in a list in **O(logN)** where **N** is size of the list. Lookup and convince yourself how a segment tree works
 [Segment Tree](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=lowestCommonAncestor) .
Let **tree** ( another list ) be the segment tree , it is twice the size of your list **l** and also its each element is another list of size two, initialized to zero.( I am taking both  **l** and  **tree** to be 1-based index ).That is for all **i** from 1 to **2N** **tree[i]=[0,0]**. **tree[i][0]** is the sum of the range this index corresponds to and **tree[i][1]** the value added to this range while updates. eg **tree[1][0]** stores sum of elements from range 1 to **N**.

```
I = [0] * int(input())
n = int(input())
j = int(input())
t=[] 
tree=[]
for i in range(j):
   s=raw_input()
   l=s.split()
   for x in range(len(l)):
       l[x]=int(l[x])
   t.append(l)

for i in range(1,2*len(I)+1):
   tree.append([0,0])

def update(pos , left , right , i , j , val):

    ####updating segment tree to add value val in list l from index i to j

    i=max(i , left)
    j=min(j , right)
    if i > j:
       return

    if i==left and j==right:
       tree[pos][0] = tree[pos][0] + val*( j - i + 1 )
       tree[pos][1] = tree[pos][1] + val
       return

    mid = (left + right)/2

    ### the range breaks down into two parts left to mid and mid+1 to right 
    ### at positions 2*pos and 2*pos+1 in tree respectively

    update(2*pos , left , mid , i , j , val)
    update(2*pos + 1 , mid+1 , right , i , j , val) 
    tree[pos][0] = tree[2*pos][0] + tree[2*pos + 1][0] + tree[pos][1]*(right - left +1 ) 


def getvalue(pos , left , right , i , j ):

    ###gets sum of elements in list from index i to j in our case
    ### i will be equal to j , will see below 

    i = max(i , left)
    j=  min(j , right)
    if i > j:
        return 0
    if i==left and j==right:
        return tree[pos][0]

    mid = (left + right)/2 
    return getvalue(2*pos , left , mid , i , j) + getvalue(2*pos+1 , mid+1 , right , i , j) + tree[pos][1]*(j - i + 1)
```

Now that your segment tree is ready we process the queries and  we just count the number of 
elements less than some value **n**.

```
for i in range( len(t) ):
    update(1 , 1 , N , t[i][0] , t[i][1] , t[i][2])

ans = 0

###Remember l is 1 based indexed
for i in range(1 , N+1):
   ###see we only use getvalue where i and j parameters of getvalue are same
   value = getvalue(1 , 1 , N , i , i) 
   if value < n:
       ans = ans + 1

print ans
```

The over all complexity of this algorithm is **O(size of (t) * logN + N)** compared to yours 
which in worst case would be **O(size of (t) * N)**. Also  as the queries were range update I 
have updated lazily ( google lazy propagation ) so that updating and querying once remain in 
**O(logN)**.

PS: Forgive my bad python.

Comment: I have a quick question that I edited onto my main question. Thanks, hob

Comment: you made sure it is 1 based index that is push N+1 [0,0] in tree

Comment: Is this correct? tree = [[0, 0]*(len(I)+1)] Both this and the main question's edit's initialization do create an IndexError.

Comment: corrected it had  forgot to write a return statement , should work fine now

Comment: shouldn't it be tree = [[0, 0]*(2*len(I)+1)]

Comment: could you give me the input i will run the code and get back

Comment: got the error t=[[0,0]*(x)] does not give what we want, so                    for i in range(1,2*(len(I)+1):                                           tree.append([0,0])

Comment: I did exactly what you said and it still returns an IndexError: list index out of range. See edit 5.

Comment: i ran on the ive input gave me no rrror

Comment: Are you using my exact code from edit 5? If you have your own version, could you paste it to me in an edit? That would be great.